# HttpListener Used Asynchronously Behaves Synchronously

Tags: .net, http, .net-4.5, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using System.Net.HttpListener BeginGetContext/EndGetContext to handle multiple http requests concurrently.  This works well on my 16 core Windows 7 SP1 desktop which handles 16 requests concurrently.  On Windows Server 2012 R2 16 Processor VM the first 2 of 20 requests are handled concurrently and then the request sequentially, e.g. the response for the third request must be sent before the request for the fourth request is looked at.

I would like the server to process the requests in a similar way to the desktop m/c ie. to process 20 requests in 8 seconds rather than the current 95 seconds.

The following log shows the behaviour on the windows 7 machine (good).  Both client and server processes are run on the Windows 7 m/c.

This is the clients log.  Each line comprises the original request by the client as echoed back by the server with the addition of the time at which it was processed by the server.  The original request comprises a sequence number and the time at which the client made the request.

Note that all requests are made at 12:46 minutes past the hour and 16 are responded to by 12:51 and the final one by 12:54.

```
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=1-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=17-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=15-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=2-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=7-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=3-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=13-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=18-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=9-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=14-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=0-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=6-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=10-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=5-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=19-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=11-client-12:46-server-12:51
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=12-client-12:46-server-12:52
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=16-client-12:46-server-12:53
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=8-client-12:46-server-12:53
http://localhost:8894/dostuff?val=4-client-12:46-server-12:54
```

The following log shows the behaviour on the Windows Server 2012 machine (bad).  Both client and server processes are run on the Windows Server 2012 m/c.

Note that the first 2 requests are processed concurrently but each subsequent request requires a sequential 5 seconds.

Note that the first 2 requests are processed concurrently but each subsequent request requires a sequential 5 seconds.  All requests are sent at 46 minutes and 39 seconds past the hour.  The first 2 requests are responded to at 46 minutes 44 seconds past the hour but the last response is received at 48 minutes and 14 seconds past the hour.

```
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=5-client-46:39-server-46:44
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=1-client-46:39-server-46:44
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=2-client-46:39-server-46:49
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=6-client-46:39-server-46:54
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=3-client-46:39-server-46:59
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=4-client-46:39-server-47:4
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=7-client-46:39-server-47:9
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=9-client-46:39-server-47:14
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=8-client-46:39-server-47:19
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=10-client-46:39-server-47:24
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=11-client-46:39-server-47:29
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=12-client-46:39-server-47:34
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=13-client-46:39-server-47:39
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=14-client-46:39-server-47:44
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=15-client-46:39-server-47:49
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=16-client-46:39-server-47:54
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=18-client-46:39-server-47:59
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=17-client-46:39-server-48:4
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=19-client-46:39-server-48:9
http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val=0-client-46:39-server-48:14
```

The code below may give some clues but I suspect it is more likely to be some quota or throttling issue on the server.

```
// SERVER build with "csc program.cs" run as program.exe
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpListener listenerLocal = new HttpListener();
        listenerLocal.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8895/");
        listenerLocal.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            //var result = listener.BeginGetContext(RequestCallback, listener);
            var resultLocal = listenerLocal.BeginGetContext((result) =>
            {
                HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    context.Request.Url.OriginalString + string.Format(
                    "-server-{0}:{1}", DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second));
                context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                System.IO.Stream output = context.Response.OutputStream;
                output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                output.Close();
            }
            , listenerLocal);
            resultLocal.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}

// CLIENT build with "csc program.cs" run as program.exe
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 20; ii++)
        {
            var thr = new System.Threading.Thread((ctr) =>
            {
                var data = new System.Net.WebClient().OpenRead(
                  string.Format("http://localhost:8895/dostuff?val={0}-client-{1}:{2}"
                  ,ctr, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second));
                var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(data);
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                data.Close();
                reader.Close();
            });
            thr.Start(ii);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThreadPool` is not best for burst tasks, instead you can use plain `Thread`

Use this for your server

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpListener listenerLocal = new HttpListener();
        listenerLocal.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8895/");
        listenerLocal.Start();    

        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (count == 20)
                continue;

            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

            var thr = new Thread(ctr =>
            {
                var l = ctr as HttpListener;
                HttpListenerContext context = l.GetContext();

                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(context.Request.Url.OriginalString + string.Format(
                    "-server-{0}:{1}", DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second));
                context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                System.IO.Stream output = context.Response.OutputStream;
                output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                output.Close();

                Interlocked.Decrement(ref count);
            });
            thr.Start(listenerLocal);
        }
    }
}
```